# How can I set a string with parenthesis and other items to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to test some of these code here http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html on my code.  To do so I need to set the codes on that page into a PHP variable, I am having trouble though.

For example this code below is incorrect just for setting it to a variable because of the "code" and 'code' the **'"** is what I am talking about.  How can I set code from that page or below into a PHP variable for testing?

```
$string = '<IMG SRC=\"javascript:alert('XSS');\"><b>hello</b> hiii';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, maybe a bit easier (you don't have to escape the quotes, nor double-quotes) would be to use [Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :

```
$string = <<<STR_1
<IMG SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');"><b>hello</b> hiii
STR_1;
```

Note you'll still have to escape the $ sign, if you have some, to not have varible interpolation.

Quoting the manual :

> Heredoc text behaves just like a
>   double-quoted string, without the
>   double quotes. This means that quotes
>   in a heredoc do not need to be
>   escaped, but the escape codes listed
>   above can still be used. Variables are
>   expanded, but the same care must be
>   taken when expressing complex
>   variables inside a heredoc as with
>   strings.

Note : read the manual about that : there are some things you must know before using heredoc syntax (like the fact that the closing identifier must be **alone** on its line)

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the quotes you used to [declare the string](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) with. So in your case the single quotes:

```
'<IMG SRC="javascript:alert(\'XSS\');"><b>hello</b> hiii'
```

Otherwise the string would be aborted with that unescaped quote.

Comment: thanks, I knew that I guess I was just hoping there was some hidden way/method I didn't know about to speed up the process, guess not though!